# Jquery.on('click') does not work on "class selector" in jQuery 1.5

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The following code http://jsfiddle.net/HCUYW/100/ does not emit click event.

```
    $(".todoitem").on('click', function() {
    alert('Item selectedd');
    });
```

The workaround is to use the **click** method directly as **$(".todoitem").click(...)**. How to make the **.on('click',...)** work on class selector ?

Comment: Did the error in the console not give this away? `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`

Comment: Maybe you should rethink the title of your question? This isn't about element ids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jquery `.on()` has been added in version 1.7+. you have used the jquery version 1.5 in fiddle. Upgrade it to any latest version 1.7+ and it will work fine or simply use `.click()` event.

```
$(".todoitem").on('click', function() {
    alert('Item selectedd');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ybmvq003/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you can't change your JQuery version right now, use the following instead

```
$(".todoitem").click(function() {
    alert('Item selectedd');
});
```

This function is available since JQuery version 1.5